# detect if NumLock is OFF and turn it always back ON

Tags: vb.net, input, keyboard

What is a method to detect if NumLock is OFF and how to turn it always back ON automatically  when my VB APP is running ?

EDIT:
My app is dedicated app, running on dedicated computer with external numpad device.

another option would be to ACCEPT NUMPAD  ARROW KEYS (etc) and convert these to NUMBERS on fly, is it possible??  (e.g. ignore the numlock off situation and behave as numlock is on)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you do this specifically in vb.net (a quick google found http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177674), but generally speaking changing machine-wide settings like this is frowned upon: users are accustomed to their individual preference for numlock (or capslock -- or whatever) key state...and you're overriding it.

This would **really** irritate me.

That said, in circumstances where your app is the only thing running (e.g., POS software, medical office management software, etc) this might be ok.

Comment: Could not agree more on the irritation factor.  @OP: Please don't do this unless your app has complete and exclusive control of the machine.

Comment: this is dedicated app in dedicated machine. It will have a unique external NUMPAD as only keyboard, it would be catastrof if user click numlock off by mistake..  any ideas?

Comment: Process the key-codes with + without numlock. So, it doesn't matter whether it is on or not.

Comment: This can be useful in circumstances where your app is the only thing running (e.g., POS software, medical office management software, etc)

Answer (score 2):

```
    Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
    Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
    Const VK_NUMLOCK = &H90
    Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = &H1
    Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" Alias "GetKeyState" (ByVal ByValnVirtKey As Integer) As Short

 Private Sub numlockON()
        keybd_event(VK_NUMLOCK, 0, 0, 0) ' Press NUMLOCK key down
        keybd_event(VK_NUMLOCK, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0) ' Release it
    End Sub

If Not GetKeyState(VK_NUMLOCK) Then numlockON()
```

Answer (score 1):

Physically remove NUMPAD key ?

Comment: I need some sort of electric shock device on my numlock key at work, so when my boss uses my computer for something, he'll be, um, reminded not to turn it off. :) (I keep telling him there are perfectly serviceable arrow keys just an inch or two away, there's no need to misappropriate my number keys, but he doesn't believe me.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Const VK_NUMLOCK = &H90
Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" Alias "GetKeyState" _
(ByVal ByValnVirtKey As Integer) As Short

Private Sub me_keyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.NumLock And Not NLKey Then
        If Not GetKeyState(VK_NUMLOCK) Then
            e.Handled = True
            NumlOn.Start()
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End sub

Private Sub NumlOn_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumlOn.Tick
    NLKey = True
    If Not GetKeyState(VK_NUMLOCK) Then numlockON()
    Application.DoEvents()
    NumlOn.Stop()
    NLKey = False
End Sub
```