# How do I get the current state of Num Lock in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

How do I get the current state of Num Lock in VB.NET?

Comment: answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938144/detect-if-numlock-is-off-and-turn-it-always-back-on

Answer (score 2):

Use the [System.Windows.Input.Keyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.aspx) class.