# Detecting the presence/absence of a numeric keypad?

Tags: keyboard

Is it possible to determine whether there is a numeric keypad connected to the system? Desktop keyboards typically have numpads, while laptops typically don't (though they put numpad keys in the normal keyboard, activated with Num Lock). Does the operating system know whether the numpad keys are physically separate? And if so, is that information exposed to programs somehow?

It would be useful to know this to determine appropriate default key-bindings. If it's not available then I'll either have to pick a conservative default (not using the numpad), which means a slightly irritating extra configuration step to get nicer behaviour for people with separate numpads, or I'll have to pick a non-conservative default and irritate the people without numpads...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can query for keyboard capabilities but iirc there is a "numpad" key. ;)

You should be able to query if `Num` is on or off, but it being off won't be a foolproof way to know that there is no numeric keypad.

What you could probably do is detect keys being pressed on a numpad and subliminaly trick the user into doing so, which would identify said characteristic.

Comment: You can actually set the status of the Numlock key (see the third answer in here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/938455/159145 ). I think (though untested) you could try setting Numlock to "on" and then detecting to see if it's still on - surely if a keyboard lacks a numlock key then checking it would reveal it's status to be off?

Comment: not sure if there has to be a key or even a numpad to enable the key via a generic api?

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably wrong, because Remote Desktop does funny stuff with the numlock key and makes me think this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

install these packages

```
sudo apt-get install -y numlockx xdotool x11-utils
```

then use a script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
cd
numlockx off &
rm -f s1.sh s2.sh out
 echo -e "#\041/bin/bash
sleep 2
xdotool key KP_5 | xev > out
exit 0" >> s1.sh
chmod +x s1.sh
echo -e "#\041/bin/bash
sleep 9
killall -9 xev
sleep 5
xdotool key BackSpace
exit 0" >> s2.sh
chmod +x s2.sh


bash s1.sh &
bash s2.sh

rm -f s1.sh s2.sh
if [[ "$(cat out | grep "keycode 84" | grep "KP_Begin" )" != "" ]]; then
  echo "Separated Numpad Detected!"
fi
rm out
exit 0
```

because `KP_Begin` is the keycode for the numpad key `KP_5` when numlock isn't active, in a real keyboard with a real keypad.
Tested on 3 PCs, one with a separated keypad e 2 without it.