# Using GLFW or Pure Java How Can We Detect If Numpad Is Present

Tags: java, glfw

My issue is that I am defaulting user controls to 3 numpad keys (KP_1, KP_2, and KP_3), which happen to feel the most natural. Granted there is an option menu to change these keys however I thought for the sake of quality of life it would be nice to detect if the user's keyboard has a keypad at all and if not default to 'J','K','L' instead.

However I can't seem to find any function in the GLFW or Java docs (such as KeyEvent) which is anything relating to "hasKey(int key)", "keyExists(int key)", or "hasNumpad()". Furthermore I can't seem to find any SO threads on the issue. Where should I be looking or what am I overlooking?

Edit: I'm using Java 8 & GLFW openGL profile 330 core. The proper solution should ideally work on: Windows, Linux, and Mac (priority ordered list).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549614/detecting-the-presence-absence-of-a-numeric-keypad  <- This question gives an interesting insight.  You could check to see if the Numlock button is on, if not you can prompt the user to either turn on the num pad or specify that they need one maybe?  This link shows how to do that task https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-read-the-status-of-num-lock-key/

Comment: @MichaelPlatt Thank you for help! If you have the power to please close as duplicate since mine is pretty much the same as that question.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the power.  Not enough cred yet :-)  But if a mod sees this and can mark it that would be great!!